# Automatically copy a row to a new sheet based on value in a specific column

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How do I automatically copy any row that contains the name `john` into another spreadsheet?

I have an example table from my Workbook below:

```
date        car color   address location   car number    name
01/09/2015  white       1abcd   uk         1234          john
04/09/2015  red         2abcd   usa        6543          jane
06/09/2015  black       7abcd   china      3789          tom
06/09/2015  blue        1abcd   uk         9876          john
06/09/2015  pink        9abcd   france     5783          brett
07/09/2015  yellow      8abcd   japan      6794          peter
```

Comment: Did you want to perform the action when the table is updated? if so you are probably best served writing a macro in vba using the Worksheet_Change event. However if you just want to copy the data with john in the row quickly, you may just want to place a filter on the name column and copy and paste the resultant rows.

Comment: You should give us some more info about *when* you want to copy the rows. As CdeoEm suggesties, a macro is a solution, but you can also build a pivot table, with the criteria in the report filter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-MY/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) with the name in the report filter and all the relevant fields as row data. Here is an example based on your data:

[image: Pivot table example]